# Cleaning project in eclipse on linux doesn't remove the Debug/Release folder

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I created a C++ hello world project in linux and I could successfully build the project and I now noticed that after cleaning the project , ***the .o files are removed but the folder Debug/Release and also the sub-directories folder is not deleted. However in windows the folders also get deleted.***
I then found out that in linux the command rm -rf is used and in windows del /F /S /Q is used. 
But -r does mean recursively and -f meaning forcefully? So why isn't the folder deleted? For it to be deleted what should have been the clean command in linux??

Comment: It is the same for VisualStudio, once created, the folders remain there, only their content is cleaned

Comment: But why does the folder get deleted when I clean the project in windows??

Comment: In eclipse or Visual Studio?

Comment: In Eclipse IDE (Juno)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be the desired behaviour as pointed out in the comments!